# EF Core: Getting the `SUM` of nested collection

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have this code:

```
decimal returned = await db.ReturnSalesDeliveries
                .Include(m => m.Items).ThenInclude(m => m.ReturnSCItem)
                .Include(m => m.ReturnSalesContract)
                .Where(m => m.ReturnSalesContract.SalesDeliveryId == sdId)
                .Select(m => m.Items.Sum(x => x.InQty * x.ReturnSCItem.Price)).DefaultIfEmpty().SumAsync();
```

It was fine when I write this using `EF`, but it was not working on `EF Core`.

Apparently it cannot be translated to SQL.

This is the error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
> aggregate or a subquery.

How can I rewrite this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite query in the following way and note that Includes are not needed if you do not load whole entity.

```cs
decimal returned = await db.ReturnSalesDeliveries
    .Where(m => m.ReturnSalesContract.SalesDeliveryId == sdId)
    .SelectMany(m => m.Items)
    .SumAsync(x => x.InQty * x.ReturnSCItem.Price);
```